# Listings: make range delimiters white, and hide block comments

Tags: listings, code, delimiters

Simply put, I'd like my range delimiters to be white so that they do not appear if I show a block of code. I would also like to omit certain block comments entirely. I've read the `listings` manual and can't figure out why this is not working.

I use the  `morecomment=[s][\color{white}]{\#~}{~\#}` option, with the markers the same as those of the range prefix/suffix.  I also want to use the `morecomment=[is]{"""~}{~"""}` option to omit block comments (Python) with the tilde after and before. I have tried putting a blackslash before the tilde as well.

Any insight? I feel like this should be an easy fix.

**LaTeX Code**

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}  % 

\lstset{
    language=Python,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small\color{blue},% just to show that colors are working
    breaklines=true,
    tabsize=4,
    escapeinside={\#`}{`},
    includerangemarker=false,
    rangeprefix={\#~},
    rangesuffix={~\#},
%   moredelim=[s][\color{white}]{\#~}{~\#},% I want to make the range delimters white, this is not working
    morecomment=[s][\color{white}]{\#~}{~\#},% I tried usign more delim, and more comment to no avail
    morecomment=[is]{"""~}{~"""},  % I want to omit block comments (invisible), this is not working
}


\begin{document}
\section{Some Sample code boxes} 
\subsection{Excerpt of Code}
\lstinputlisting[
language=Python,
linerange=beg:def-end:def,
]{Ex.py}
\subsection{Full Code, delimiters hidden}
\lstinputlisting[%
caption={Some Python code},%
language=Python%
]{Ex.py}
\end{document}
```

**Ex.py Python Code**

```
"""
Some block comment
"""
"""~
Some block comment I want omitted entirely
~"""

# I want the range delimiters below whited out so they do not appear on the full code block
#~beg:def~#
def y(x, a=1, b=1, c=1):
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c   #`\label{lin1}`
#~end:def~#

Some_other_code = 1
```